# What concept use in this laravel route

Tags: php, laravel

I got a source code and I tried to reference it. It has strange codes which are not usual with Laravel.

It uses routes as shown below :

```
<?php

/**
 * Global Routes
 * Routes that are used between both frontend and backend.
 */

// Switch between the included languages
Route::get('lang/{lang}', 'LanguageController@swap');

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/*
* Frontend Routes
* Namespaces indicate folder structure
*/
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Frontend', 'as' => 'frontend.'], function () {
    includeRouteFiles(__DIR__ . '/Frontend/');
});

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/*
* Backend Routes
* Namespaces indicate folder structure
*/
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Backend', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    /*
     * These routes need view-backend permission
     * (good if you want to allow more than one group in the backend,
     * then limit the backend features by different roles or permissions)
     *
     * Note: Administrator has all permissions so you do not have to specify the administrator role everywhere.
     */
    includeRouteFiles(__DIR__ . '/Backend/');
});
```

**includeRouteFiles helper function**

```
if (!function_exists('includeRouteFiles')) {

    /**
     * Loops through a folder and requires all PHP files
     * Searches sub-directories as well.
     *
     * @param $folder
     */
    function includeRouteFiles($folder)
    {
        try {
            $rdi = new recursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
            $it = new recursiveIteratorIterator($rdi);

            while ($it->valid()) {
                if (!$it->isDot() && $it->isFile() && $it->isReadable() && $it->current()->getExtension() === 'php') {
                    require $it->key();
                }

                $it->next();
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

And it has backend ,frontend and breadcrumbs files in routes.

Photo of the routes files :

[image: routes files]

> Can anyone explain me what concept is used in this?

Comment: Can you post the source code of the includeRouteFiles() function? I don't think it is a Laravel function

Comment: this is in helper function

Comment: What is the location of this file? Any what version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially just a base routes file that will look for look for any other file that will (in this case) recursively look in a `Frontend` and `Backend` folder in the same directory as the routes file for any other php file any require it in e.g.

if you had a file at `routes/Frontend/post.php`:

```
<?php

Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController);
```

It would load this in to your routes file inside the `Route::group` for the frontend.

This would allow you to separate out your routes files in to smaller sections without having to reference them in the base file and it will also add some default values to those routes as well i.e. for the `Frontend` section it will apply the `namespace` and a prefix for the route names and for the `Backend` is will apply a `namespace`, uri `prefix`, a prefix for the `name` and also `middleware`.