# Laravel is duplicating routes

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel 8.40 backend with many routes, and when I was adding scribe to the project I realized that many routes are twice listed.

Calling `php artisan route:list` as example, it will duplicate the route `api/hq/v1/account/login`, removing the `v1/account` portion:

```
POST    api/hq/login            login   App\Http\Controllers\Hq\Account@logIn
POST    api/hq/v1/account/login login   App\Http\Controllers\Hq\Account@logIn
```

I want to have just `api/hq/v1/account/login`.

#### routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'hq'], function(){
    includeRouteFiles(__DIR__.'/api/hq/');
});
```

#### routes/api/hq/index.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function(){
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'account'], function(){
        includeRouteFiles(__DIR__ .  '/account/');
    });
});
```

#### routes/api/hp/account/index.php

```
Route::post('/login', [Account::class, 'logIn'])->name('login');
```

Already ran `php artisan route:clear`.

...

How can I fix it?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: did you try to clear route cache? `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: you could also try to delete `cache/route.php` based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37879020/13933721

Comment: Yes, I already cleared it many times, and it is still happening.

Comment: what do those `includeRouteFiles(...)` contains? that self made thingy might be able to point to the same controller twice, but [who knows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51797366). especially the routes they append into the list.

Comment: The include in `api.php` is directly including both files  `routes/api/hq/index.php` **and** `routes/api/hp/account/index.php`. So it is normal that you get the route `'/api/hq/'` + `'/login'` when the second one is included. It all comes back to the method `includeRouteFiles` which includes also subdirectory files.

Comment: try `php artisan optimize`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`includeRouteFiles` is a helper method from [laravel-boilerplate](https://laravel-boilerplate.com/index.html) that uses [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-boilerplate/blob/a91de1efacc38eea14b46a898c99e9b1b5d45636/app/Helpers/Global/SystemHelper.php#L13C24-L13C50) to get the list of route files to be included.

If you call `includeRouteFiles` in a route file that is already being included by the same method, you'll load its routes twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can try change this.

```
//1st
Route::group(['prefix' => 'hq'], function(){
    includeRouteFiles(__DIR__.'/api/hq/');
});

//2nd
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function(){
   Route::group(['prefix' => 'account'], function(){
      includeRouteFiles(__DIR__ .  '/account/');
 });
});
```

Into

```
//1st
Route::prefix('hq')->group(__DIR__.'/web/api/hq/index.php');
//2nd
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function(){
   Route::prefix('account')->group(__DIR__.'/web/api/hq/account/index.php');
});
```

Now you should have api/hq/v1/account/login.

Note

```
 includeRouteFiles(__DIR__ .  '/api/hq/');
//This will include all files in directories and subdirectories of /api/hq/ recursively.
```

Answer is based on [Organizing your routes](https://darkghosthunter.medium.com/laravel-organizing-your-routes-into-several-files-1f3f8ba09f49)